# How to read a CSV file in Pandas with quote characters?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a csv file dataset that looks like this:

[dataset header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SsUz.png)

```
Date,"TTF_1M_15m","Own Trades (Sell)","Own Trades (Buy)"
2022-01-03 09:00:00,"68.54485294117647","",""
2022-01-03 09:15:00,"66.46498579545455","",""
2022-01-03 09:30:00,"69.53991935483872","",""
.......
```

I'm having trouble reading this into pandas due to the quotations.

So far I've been trying to use this line of code but I am just getting error messages:

```
data = pd.read_csv("APE_Data_Export_15min_2022.csv", sep=',', engine='python')
```

I would like the first line to indicate the 3 columns: TTF_1M_15m, Own Trades (Sell), Own Trades (Buy) with corresponding data underneath.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:760, in PythonParser._next_iter_line(self, row_num)
    759 assert self.data is not None
--> 760 line = next(self.data)
    761 # for mypy

Error: ',' expected after '"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv("APE_Data_Export_15min_2022.csv", sep=',', engine='python')

Comment: You should put the error into the question (with correct formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using,

```
df = pd.read_csv('APE_Data_Export_15min_2022.csv', sep=',', engine='python').replace('"','', regex=True)
```

Output:
[image]

OUTPUT with actual data:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I get a parser error, Error: ',' expected after '"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('APE_Data_Export_15min_2022.csv', sep=',', engine='python').replace('"','', regex=True)

Comment: I just ran the code with the data given, it ran perfectly fine, i'll share the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: Hmm yeah it seems to work fine for you...I have pd version 1.4.2, python version 3.9.12

Comment: It should work with the versions mentioned. Can you share CSV file with first 5 rows so that I can check on my system as well?

Comment: Date,"TTF_1M_15m","Own Trades (Sell)","Own Trades (Buy)"
2022-01-03 09:00:00,"68.54485294117647","",""
2022-01-03 09:15:00,"66.46498579545455","",""
2022-01-03 09:30:00,"69.53991935483872","",""
2022-01-03 09:45:00,"71.08550135501355","",""
2022-01-03 10:00:00,"69.90805841924399","",""
2022-01-03 10:15:00,"69.5328","",""
2022-01-03 10:30:00,"67.70011210762331","",""

Comment: Apologies, I'm a bit new to the site, couldn't see a way to attach a csv file to my question. Hope the above paste works?

Comment: I still had no problem running the code. I have shared the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: I managed to make it work with this: df_raw = pd.read_csv('APE_Data_Export_15min_2022.csv').replace('"','', regex=True)
df=df_raw.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand = True)
columntitles = df_raw.columns.str.replace('"','', regex=True).tolist()[0].split(',')
df.columns = columntitles